# Need a generic xpath for the following html code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Following is the HTML code for which I need a unique XPath.
Firebug gives me a xpath like

```
.//*[@id='service_dlg']/form/p[4]/span/input[1] [For Essential]
```

`.//*[@id='service_dlg']/form/p[4]/span/input[2] [For Enhanced]` etc.

I need something like `[@name = 'Essential']` so that I need not write multiple xpaths in my code. I want to pass values like `essential, enhanced and premium` from a function.

```
<p>
<label style="vertical-align:top">Feature Pack:</label>
<span style="display:inline-block">
<input name="pack" value="Essential" type="radio">
<label class="feature">Essential</label>
<input name="pack" value="Enhanced" type="radio">
<label class="feature">Enhanced</label>
<input name="pack" value="Premium" type="radio">
<label class="feature">Premium</label>
<br>
<input name="featurepack" value="u" type="checkbox">
<label class="feature">URL Filtering</label>
<br>
<input name="featurepack" value="t" type="checkbox">
<label class="feature">Threat Prevention</label>
<br>
<input name="featurepack" value="w" type="checkbox">
<label class="feature">Wildfire</label>
<br>
</span>
```

Comment: I would just use css selector `input[name=pack][value="Essential"]` where you can put variable instead of Essential. CSS selectors are much better than xpath

Comment: It did not work. I tried the css selector suggested by you on firebug and it says no matching node  found.

Comment: Is it an IFRAME? Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: No its not an iframe. its an enterprise GUI, not available on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as follows for `Enhanced`:

```
//input[@value='Enhanced']
```

To make it generic and receive value as a function parameter, try as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='%s']" % value) # where value is function parameter, can be Essential, Enhanced or Premium
```

Comment: Best way to say thanks in SO is by accepting and upvoting the answer. As you are new comer, just informing that ...

Comment: My bad. I accepted the answer. Thank you very much once again.